# Object reference not set to an instance of an object: What am i not doing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the get and post methods for my create View in my controller. When i run this, it gives me an error: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}  The rest of the code is the create get and post methods.. Does anyone pehaps know what i could be doing wrong?

```
// GET: /Title/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new title
    {
        create_dt = DateTime.Now,
        last_maint_dt = DateTime.Now,
        row_version = 1,
        status = "ACTIVE",
        user_id = currentUser.UserName,
        last_user_id = currentUser.UserName

    }; 

    return View(model);
}


// POST: /Title/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(title title)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.titles.Add(title);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        currentUser = Membership.GetUser(false);

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            userid = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
        }
    }
        var model = new title
        {
            create_dt = DateTime.Now,
            last_maint_dt = DateTime.Now,
            row_version = 1,
            status = "ACTIVE",
            user_id = currentUser.UserName,
            last_user_id = currentUser.UserName
        };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: do you have a stack trace for us?

Comment: Where does the error occur? What is `db` and where do you initialize it?

Comment: Debugger should also give you the error location. This is important piece of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're conditionally calling `Membership.GetUser` and clearly expecting that it *can* return null... and if the request isn't authenticated you're not even assigning a value to `currentUser`. However, you're then fetching `currentUser.UserName` twice when constructing the model. That will obviously fail if `currentUser` is null.

Really, you should look at the stack trace of the exception - that should show you where things are going wrong.

Comment: i got the solution.... i put the if clause in the wrong method.. it was supposed to be in th httpget method. thnx guys :-)